# Twig refactoring large templates with reusable blocks

Tags: php, templates, twig

I have tried to understand how to use `extend`,`embed` and `use` tags for solving my problem. But it does not work when I have split my entire template into many files to reduce complexity.

After the splits, the blocks defined in sub files cant be overridden in my final child template. How can this be done in Twig?

It appears after reading lot of docs and SOs, twig likes to have big template files. Im not asking for multiple inheritance. Im just asking to be able to split complex parent templates into blocks that are defined in separate files, and yet supporting to override any block in the whole tree.